# Can't fetch route params or query in asyncdata on production with nuxtjs

Tags: javascript, wordpress, axios, nuxt.js, vue-router

I've built a search page which sends a request to the wordpress json api. The asyncData method gets it params by submitting a form in a header component. On submit I call the `this.$router.push({ name: 'suche', params: {search: this.searchInput}})`. On localhost with npm run dev everything works like it should. But when I deploy the route.params.search is undefined in asyncData. I tested to display $route.params.search and it works on both local and production mode (target: static).

asyncData in suche.vue:

```
async asyncData({route, $axios }) {
            try {
                // console.log(params.search);
                // const anfrage = params.search;
                const query = route.params.search
                const search = await $axios.$get(`https://wp-api.com/wp-json/wp/v2/multiple-post-type?search=${query}&type[]=post&type[]=project&per_page=20&_embed`)
                return { search }
            } catch (error) {
                if (error.response) {
                    // Request made and server responded
                    console.log(error.response.data)
                    console.log(error.response.status)
                    console.log(error.response.headers)
                } else if (error.request) {
                    // The request was made but no response was received
                    console.log(error.request)
                } else {
                    // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
                    console.log('Error', error.message)
                }
            }
    }
```

I also tested the router push with path and query.

Comment: `I  tested to display $route.params.search and it works on both local and production mode` what is not working so? Also, did you `yarn build` (or generate) and `yarn start` to see if it works locally? Maybe it's just a matter of env variables?

Comment: @kissu $route.params.search works in html when I display it e.g. <p>{{$route.params.search}}</p>. But in the method asyncData the parameter route is undefined. Does "nuxt generate" equal yarn generate or is it "npm generate"?

Comment: Do you type the URL or hard refresh to your page or do you navigate to it? Also, check in your server console, if you don't have a `console.log` there. Use either `yarn` or `npm` depending on what you already have in your project.

Comment: @kissu When I submit the form I get redirected to the /suche page via this.$router.push... and the input of the form is transferred as param of the router push.